# Creating MATLAB 3d plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a matrix let it be called `ARR`

```
size(ARR) = 3600 x 140
```

Where it stands for 3600 seconds, 140 nodes, and in each place `ARR(t,n) = value`

How to create a 3d plot to show this ARR?

When I do `surface(ARR)` I get nothing, and when I do `plot(ARR)` I get 140 lines.

How in `plot(ARR)` can I add legend to know which line has which color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for instance use [`surf(ARR)`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) or [`mesh(ARR)`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html). See the documentation for further usage.

For your plot problem you can use [`legend`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) but it may not be very handy with 140 curves.